# Big-O of an infinite geometric series?

Tags: big-o, discrete-mathematics

Say I have the following series:

[image]

How would I go about calculating the big-O of this, if at all? The geometric  series sum of this series is 01.25. Pulling the n out reveals that the answer to the equation is 01.25n. Does that mean that this is O(n)? Or does the fact that the series is infinite mean that there is no solution at all?

Comment: `Does that mean that this is O(n)?`. Yes. Usually your sum is actually finite, but you can bound it by infinite sum (since all terms are positive). Since the latter one converges, the former one is constant-bounded.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.